# it's a bug or feature? Lua@OpenComputers@minecraft

Tags: lua, load, environment

```
local e={print=print, load=load, a='2'}
e._G=e
load(
[[
  print(a) 
  load("print(a)")()
]]
, '', '', e)()
```

--expected result

```
2
2
```

--but in reality

```
2
1
```

Why does "load" not get the environment for the compiled chunk from the environment?

Comment: What version of lua is this? Where is the value `1` coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-load

> If the resulting function has upvalues, the first upvalue is set to the value of env, if that parameter is given, **or to the value of the global environment.**

I.e. no matter where you are now in terms of `_ENV`, missing `env` argument to `load` will connect loaded chunk to very global environment.

If you want the loaded source in 5.2 to inherit new environment by default, substitute `load` / `loadfile` functions:

```
e.load = function (ld, src, mode, env)
    return load(ld, src, mode, env or e)
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I have come to the same decision. But in my opinion, this behavior load () violates the principles of Lua.

Comment: Which one? :) [comment length padding block]

Comment: If I compile a chunk specify the environment E, then I expect that everything will work in this chunk, will only see the environment E as global. But if I call the load inside this chunk, it gains access to the highest global environment.

Comment: This is not a principle, and not the only hole to escape the sandbox. http://lua-users.org/wiki/SandBoxes

Comment: Thanks for the link. I do not understand what it means to "table - UNSAFE - modifying this table could affect code outside the sandbox"

Comment: @Bogdan It means that `table`, `math`, `coroutine`, etc. are massively shared core libraries (exported as tables), not protected from changes by default. You may replace e.g. `table.insert` with your own implementation and benefit from misbehaviors introduced this way into "more privileged" code.

Comment: If, for example, some privileged module registers new package loaders into global `package.loaders` using `table.insert`, then you can change the order of insertion, thus breaking its loading logic in unpredictable way that may be exploited.

Comment: local function tablecopy(t)
  local r={}
  for k,v in pairs(t) do
    r[k]=v
    if type(v)=='table' and v~=t then
      r[k]=tablecopy(v)
    end
  end
  return r
end

Comment: I use this recursive function for make copy of environment: "local _E=tablecopy(_G) _E._G=_E" This will help isolate the environment?

Comment: Deep copy, even if implemented properly against non-trivial reference loops, does not guarantee that there are no proxying metatables in the way. If you can, just construct tables with only known SAFE functions (or safe reimplementatons like we did for load()) and pass them into new env. Generic sandboxing is hard-to-impossible thing in Lua and in general, *afaik*.

Comment: Search solutions unsolvable problem - a good way to learn)
Thank you for your informative answers. Best wishes.